# Django reset password doesn't load correct templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have 4 custom templates but two of them are loading the default templates and I don't know why. This is my url paths:

```
#works fine
path('reset_password/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="myapp/password_reset.html"),
     name="reset_password"),

#doesn't work
path('reset_password_sent/', 
      auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="myapp/password_reset_sent.html"), 
      name="password_reset_done"),

#works fine
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="myapp/password_reset_form.html"), 
     name="password_reset_confirm"),

#doesn't work
path('reset_password_complete/', 
     auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="myapp/password_reset_done.html"), 
     name="password_reset_complete"),
```

However, if I write the URL directly in the browser they load correctly.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you used 'app_name' in your 'urls.py'?

Comment: yes, app_name=myapp and in the main urls.py: 

path('', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Django does not use a namespace when reversing the password reset urls.py. You must be removing 'app_name' from your urls.py.